# SSRS - Show textbox if string contains numbers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to convert the following SQL Server expression into a visibility expression in SSRS for a certain textbox that contains an error message:

```
select address, commonPlaceName, municipality where @Location not like '$[0-9]%'
```

My SSRS report lets users search for @Location, which is a combination of the address and commonPlaceName and returns a table of records.

I am trying to limit the number of rows returned based on both the character length and whether the parameter value supplied contains a number.I want to show an error message when they search for a common place or address without a number that says "Sorry your search was too broad so the number of records has been limited".

I got the length part to work by using the following:

```
=iif(len(Parameters!Location.Value)<=5,false,true)
```

But I can't figure out how to search for a number in a string

For those interested, in the SQL script, I am setting the rowcount based on a case statement that parallels the visibility options I am trying to set in SSRS.

I am still learning SSRS so any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

Below is the SQL statement I am using to limit rowcount if that helps:

```
declare @top int

set @top = case when len(@Location) <= 5 then 100
            when @Location not like '%[0-9]%' then 100
            when len(@Location) >5 then 0
       end

set rowcount @top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I found a workaround for now. I ended up creating a new dataset:

```
select 

'LocationWithNum' = case 
                         when @Location like '%[0-9]%' then 'true'
                         else 'false'
                    end
```

Then I changed the visibility expression of the error message textbox to the following:

```
=iif(len(Parameters!Location.Value)<=5 or First(Fields!LocationWithNum.Value, "LocationWithNum") = false, false, true)
```

So far this seems to work well. Let me know if you guys think of anything else!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. Calculate the visibility in your query and set the Visibility to the calculated query field. This is cleaner in the report. Normally you would want to put all display logic in the report itself, however, I have been lazy a time or two.

   =IIF(Fields!ShouldShowField.Value==1,0,1)
2. Use SSRS functions such as `InStr()` or

   =IIF(Regex.Replace(Fields!MyField.Value, "[MyRegExString]").Length ==  Fields!MyField.Value.Length, 0, 1)
3. Use Custom Code for advanced string manipulation and call your code similar to

   =IIF(Code.ShouldShowTextBox(Fields!MyField.Value),0,1)

Comment: Thanks Ross. Number 1 will not work because I am setting the rowcount based on a case statement to avoid unnecessary server load. Could you explain number 2 a little more? I am confused by your use of fields instead of my @Location parameter and also I am unsure of what replaces "[MyRegExString]". Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my original question to include the SQL code I am using to limit rowcount if that helps.

Comment: If you want to check the value of a parameter then substitute Fields!FieldName,Value with Parameters!Location.Value. As for the regex, you may be able to get away with [0-9]. I am not a regex expert and would not want to give misleading advice there.